# Calculate relationship between 2 different pairs of x and y coordinates on different maps

Tags: modeling

I have 2 maps with different pairs of x and y coordinates.

Let's say both maps represent the Atlantic Ocean, and the coordinates represent treasures hidden in secret islands.

Sometimes, when winning battles against other ships, we are able to get pieces of MAP 1 from their crew which reveal the whereabouts of these treasures. I then have to inform the captain of their whereabouts. The only problem is that MAP 1 is in a shape and form only understood by the enemy so I have to convert it to the more intuitive MAP 2. That way my captain and the rest of the crew can understand it.

So... good news and bad news. The good news is that we recently won a battle against some Viking pirates and found a piece of MAP 1. Below are the coordinates:

```
MAP 1 X,MAP 1 Y
10, 9
11, 9
12, 9
13, 9
14, 9
15, 9
16, 9
17, 9
18, 9
19, 9
20, 9
21, 9
22, 9
23, 9
24, 9
15, 8
16, 8
17, 8
18, 8
19, 8
20, 8
21, 8
22, 8
23, 8
24, 8
```

The bad news is that the cartographer we had on board, Dick 'Mad Eyes' Wheatley, was killed and I don't know how to convert these coordinates to MAP 2's coordinates.

Mad Eyes left some notes containing the mapping of coordinates from MAP 1 to MAP 2. This is just a small extract so let me know if you need more.

```
MAP 1 X,MAP 2 X,MAP 1 Y,MAP 2 Y
21, 2824,   3,  5969
22, 2836,   3,  5971
23, 2848,   3,  5974
24, 2860,   3,  5976
4,  2959,   12, 5997
5,  2971,   12, 6000
6,  2983,   12, 6002
7,  2994,   12, 6004
8,  3006,   12, 6006
9,  3018,   12, 6009
10, 3030,   12, 6011
11, 3041,   12, 6013
12, 3053,   12, 6016
13, 3065,   12, 6018
14, 3077,   12, 6020
15, 3089,   12, 6022
16, 3100,   12, 6025
17, 3112,   12, 6027
18, 3124,   12, 6029
19, 3136,   12, 6032
20, 3147,   12, 6034
21, 3159,   12, 6036
22, 3171,   12, 6038
23, 3183,   12, 6041
24, 3195,   12, 6043
4,  2955,   11, 6015
5,  2967,   11, 6018
6,  2979,   11, 6020
7,  2990,   11, 6022
8,  3002,   11, 6024
9,  3014,   11, 6027
10, 3026,   11, 6029
11, 3037,   11, 6031
12, 3049,   11, 6034
13, 3061,   11, 6036
14, 3073,   11, 6038
15, 3085,   11, 6040
16, 3096,   11, 6043
17, 3108,   11, 6045
18, 3120,   11, 6047
19, 3132,   11, 6050
20, 3143,   11, 6052
21, 3155,   11, 6054
22, 3167,   11, 6056
23, 3179,   11, 6059
24, 3191,   11, 6061
7,  2987,   10, 6039
8,  2999,   10, 6041
9,  3011,   10, 6044
10, 3023,   10, 6046
11, 3034,   10, 6048
12, 3046,   10, 6051
13, 3058,   10, 6053
14, 3070,   10, 6055
15, 3082,   10, 6057
16, 3093,   10, 6060
17, 3105,   10, 6062
18, 3117,   10, 6064
19, 3129,   10, 6067
20, 3140,   10, 6069
21, 3152,   10, 6071
22, 3164,   10, 6073
23, 3176,   10, 6076
24, 3188,   10, 6078
```

I tried doing basic statistical analysis on this: correlation, linear regression... Stuff that I learned at the "Ultimate Pirate Statistics Crash Course" (what a waste of gold!). But this didn't yield any useful results. There is very little relationship between the coordinates (at least linear).

In case of usefulness, these are the min and max for the coordinates:

```
MAP 1 X: 0 - 52
MAP 1 Y: 1 - 47
MAP 2 X: 90 - 6791
MAP 2 Y: 90 - 6801
```

What can I do? Please help a young pirate and you will get 50% of the treasure! RRRRRRRRRRRR!

Comment: If you describe [the real problem, with its real context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl), we can give you better advice.

Comment: Guess stackoverflow hit the nail on the head with [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) article the other day. @Kodiologist there is no difference between the real problem and the one described above other than what the maps refer to and the reason for having to convert MAP 1 to MAP 2. I am even using data from the real problem... How would the mathematical challenge change if I told you I had to map basketball arena seats instead?

Comment: It wouldn't. The issue is that data analysis isn't just mathematics: choosing the right formalism is often the most difficult part of a data-analysis problem. Passive-aggressively accusing people who are trying to help you of being unwelcoming is a good way to not get helped, as is refusing to describe what you actually need help with.

Comment: @Kodiologist the reason I am not giving you the real context is because most people here don't work in my niche and aren't familiar with the terms that would appear in the real context. I'm trying to simplify it for everyone making it a tat funny and easier to digest thus making the question easier to approach. Giving you the real context would make it worse, and harder for me to explain as well. If you can't help me with what I gave you then you can't help me. You are kind of being unwelcoming by shifting all your focus on nuances that don't change anything in the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

[image]

It’s a plot of the line segments from Map 1 coordinates to adjusted Map 2 coordinates, specifically, from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(\frac{x_2}{50}-55,\frac{y_2}{50}-118)$, where segments with $y_1$-coordinates of $3$, $10$, $11$, and $12$ are colored black, blue, green, and red, respectively. (You can see that the Map-1-coordinate ends of the segments are above the adjusted Map 2 ends.) The scaling and shifting was done to bring the Map 2 points you provided closer to their corresponding Map 1 points on a regular $x$-$y$ graph.

The direction of the segments from Map 1 coordinates to Map 2 coordinates changes (consistently) as the Map 1 $y$-coordinate changes, and an increase of $1$ in the Map 1 $x$-coordinate corresponds to an increase in the (adjusted) Map 2 coordinate that looks constant for each fixed $y_1$ value.

Clearly a pattern. Maybe you can figure the rest out?

---

**Additional information added at OP’s request:**

My first observation was a pattern in the group of Map 1 coordinates $(4,12)$ to $(24,12)$, which you listed consecutively. In this group, for each increase by $1$ in the first Map 1 coordinate $x_1$, the Map 2 $x_2$-value increased by $11$ or $12$ and the Map 2 $y_2$-value increased by $2$ or $3$. It seemed likely these were constant increases by $11$-point-something and $2$-point-something per unit increase in $x_1$, rounded to integers. [Looking for this kind of pattern is probably the most important part of solving the problem, and it’s a pretty standard first thought if you think there might be near-perfect linear relationships in the mix, which wouldn’t be surprising for changes in geometric coordinate systems, the context of your question. (Yes, the pretend context you gave was actually helpful!)]

I saw that this pattern seemed to hold for the other groups of Map 1 coordinates you gave: points $(x_1,11)$, points $(x_1,10)$, and points $(x_1,3)$.

However, this doesn’t answer the whole question, because, for example, it doesn’t reveal how to find Map 2 coordinates for Map 1’s $(x_1,y_1)$ unless you know the Map 2 coordinates for at least one Map 1 point with the same $y_1$-value.

Unfortunately, what happens to Map 2 coordinates for a fixed Map 1 $x_1$-value as Map 1 $y_1$ changes wasn’t as straightforward. For example, the Map 2 coordinates for the Map 1 points $(24,3)$, $(24,10)$, $(24,11)$, and $(24,12)$ were, respectively, $(2860,5976)$, $(3188,6078)$, $(3191,6061)$, and $(3195,6043)$. The Map 2 $x_2$ values corresponding to Map 1 points $(x_1,24)$ rise (but not linearly) as $x_1$ increases through the values $3$, $10$, $11$, $12$ (from $2860$ to $3188$ to $3191$ to $3195$), but $x_2$ first increases as $x_1$ goes from $3$ to $10$, then decreases as $x_1$ goes to $11$ and to $12$.

I stopped thinking about the algebra and decided to look geometrically at segments connecting Map 1 coordinates to their corresponding Map 2 coordinates. Without modifying any coordinates, the picture was hard to resolve, because all the Map 1 coordinates were “close” on axes that had enough range to display both Maps’ coordinates. Here’s what I saw.

[image]

[Aside: Correlation can reveal linear relationships, too, but it’s always helpful to look at the data before calculating statistics to get an idea of what’s going on. After looking, you might notice the linear relationships within each group of points with a fixed $y_1$-value; then regressions between $x_1$ and $y_i$ for each $i$ separately would give you something. If you take all the points together, you probably wouldn’t see much from regression, because there isn’t a single linear relationship going on.]

After seeing the picture above, I tried to reveal more detail by dividing all the Map 2 coordinates by 100. That gave me this picture.

[image]

(Note: For what it’s worth, I did these calculations in Excel, where I’d copied your data to, and then created the plots with Mathematica. Mathematica doesn’t display axes at $x=0$ and $y=0$ by default, and I was also accidentally plotting only the points with Map 1 coordinates of 11 or 12, due to a copy/paste slip.)

I figured I was getting close and just kept playing with various scaling and translations to get the Map 1 and Map 2 coordinates closer and relatively spread out. I finally added colors to make it easier to see the different $y_2$-value groups.

I figured I’d gotten far enough that the end was in sight, but finishing it up and getting exact conversion formulas was going to be a little boring and I was lazy.

Hope that helps, and that it all seems less magical now!

Comment: Please edit your response to include how you got to these findings. This is honestly magic to me. Much obliged.

Comment: No problem. I added a description of what I did and thought to my original answer.

Comment: thanks so much for walking me over your thought process. It really is useful. Even after understanding what you did, it still is incredible that I was able to rebuild a map of over 100k coordinates with the little you gave me. Definitely less magical but still magical!